# No sound output or input available (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, alsa

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new laptop (Schenker Vision 15 E23) and do not have sound.

The sound options only offer the selection of the Dummy-Output and I have tried a few days with a lot of ways that are already offered on this forum and many more, but none has solved my issue yet.

I have changed

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1"`

This at least got alsa to detect my soundcard, but it still does not offer the selection in the options.

I have also added my user to the audio group.

`aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` looks like it is working with the output of

`Wiedergabe: WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate: 48000 Hz, mono` but there is no sound either.

Adding `generic` with `options snd_hda_intel model=` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` has made the HDMI sound appear, but everything else is still not available.

`inxi -A` outputs:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A
  Device-2: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

`lspci | grep -i audio` outputs

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
```

`hwinfo --sound` outputs the following:

```
20: PCI 1f.3: 0401 Multimedia audio controller
[Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: nS1_.ftumtKOqj08
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Device Name: "Onboard - Sound"
  Model: "Intel Multimedia audio controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x51c8 
  SubVendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x3022 
  Revision: 0x01
  Driver: "sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl"
  Driver Modules: "snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl"
  Memory Range: 0x603e1e0000-0x603e1e3fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x603e000000-0x603e0fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 195 (59 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d000051C8sv00008086sd00003022bc04sc01i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

I have also tried installing Windows temporarily to check if the hardware works and it works on Windows.

I have no other ideas on how to proceed and would be really grateful for any help. If you need any more information, feel free to ask and I will provide it.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!